# Yesod WebSocketsT handler cleanup

Tags: haskell, websocket, yesod

I'm currently authoring an application in Haskell that relies on Yesod and its web sockets implementation.

I was wondering what is the correct way to acquire and release resources for a WebSocketT handler.

For example, in the following naive case...

```
chatApp :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
chatApp = do
    let outgoingFlow = forever $ deliverOutgoingMessages
    let incomingFlow = forever $ deliverIncomingMessages
    bracket_ acquireResource
             releaseResource
             (race_ outgoingFlow incomingFlow)
```

... `releaseResource` does not seem to be called when a client disconnects abruptly or purposefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing over the weekend. This is essentially a replication of how web socket background ping process works, apart for the fact that I'm not swallowing the ping send exception when the other end is no longer reachable, but rather using it to detect the disconnection.

```hs
echoApp' :: WebSocketsT Handler ()
echoApp' = do
  conn <- ask
  let acquire = putStrLn "Acquiring..."
      release = putStrLn "Releasing"
      hardWork = (threadDelay 600000000)
      ping i = do
          threadDelay (30 * 1000 * 1000)
          WS.sendPing conn (T.pack $ show i)
          ping (i + 1)

  liftIO $ bracket_ acquire release $ race_ hardWork (ping 1)
```

The downside of this approach is that there's still an up to 30 seconds window when the web socket process is lingering, but at least the resource gets eventually released in a more or less controllable way.